# Is it possible to add/update a sorted list in constant time?

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

Suppose you are given a list of integers that have already been sorted such as (1,7,13,14,50). It should be noted that the list will contain no duplicates.

Is there some data structure that could store this while allowing me to add any new element (at it's proper location) in constant time? add(10) would yield (1,7,10,13,14,50).

Similarly, would I be able to update an element (such as changing 7 to 19) and shift the order accordingly in constant time? change(7,19) yields (1,13,14,19,50).

For a class I need to write a data structure that performs these operations as quickly as possible, but I just wanted to know if constant time could be done and if not, then what would the ideal runtime be?

Comment: In list you would still require `O(n)` to locate the element. HashMap takes `O(1)` to locate the element.

Comment: _"Is it possible to add/update a sorted list in constant time?"_ vs _"performs these operations as quickly as possible,"_ is kinda contradiction. As per my understanding "constant time" means: regardless where the operation needs to be done it always takes the same amount of time. A "quick as possible" solution will be faster for about 50% of all cases then a "constant time" solution.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve. Do you really need to maintain a sorted list? Or do you just need a data structure that will allow you to insert and update items efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To insert in constant time, O(1), this would only occur as a best case for any of the data structures. Hash tables generally have the best insertion time, but it might not always be O(1) if there are collisions and there is separate chaining. You do not sort a hash  so the complexity is irrelevent.

Binary tree's have a good insertion time, and as a bonus, it is sorted already upon inserting a new node. This takes on average O(logn) time however. The best case for inserting is O(1) if the tree is empty.

Those were just a couple examples, see here for more info on the complexities of these operations: http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Answer (score 0):

In general? No. Determining where to insert a new element or re-ordering the list after insertion involves performing analysis of the list's contents, which involves reading the elements of the list, which (in general) means iterating over some portion of the length of the list. This (again, in general) is dependant on how many elements are in the list, which by definition is not a constant. Hence, a constant-time sorted insert is simply not possible except in special cases.

Answer (score 0):

A binary tree, TreeSet, would be adequate. An array with Arrays.binarySearch and Arrays.copy would be fine too because here we have ints, and then we do not need the wrapper class Integer.

For real constant time, O(1), one must pay in space. Use a **BitSet**. To add 17 simply set 17 to true. There are optimized methods to find the next set bit and so on.

But I doubt optimizing is really needed at this spot. File I/O might pay off more.

Comment: Whether `BitSet` would be reasonable rather depends on the range of his numbers. As you say, you pay in space. If his range is 32-bit integers, he would need half a gigabyte (2^32 bits is 2^29 bytes).